# Copied array is being affected by changing the original array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm quite stunned with this weird problem. I'm trying to constantly add records to some `$array`, copying it to `$cloned` and then passing `$cloned` to `batchInsert`, which, by design, adds key `_id` to the array. I see unexpected behavior when I try to dump contents of the original array, which should have no reference with `$cloned` (copied) array. Instead, `_id` appear both in `$array` and `$cloned`, which is quite weird and I can't imagine what's happening.

This code gives me expected bahaviour

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $array[] = $i;
    $cloned = $array;
    passToFunction($cloned);
    print_r($array); // expecting not to have anything added to that array
}

function passToFunction(&$b) {
    $b["test"] = new Obj();
}

class Obj {
    public $test = "test";
}
```

results, correctly, in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
.
.
.
.
```

However, in case I use MongoDB driver,

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB("test");
$users = $db->users;

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $array[] = array("number" => $i);
        $cloned = $array;
        $users->batchInsert($cloned);
        print_r($array);
}
```

gives me following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 55a7f2bbd04aa45b228b4567
                )

        )

)
```

note the `_id` key, which shouldn't be in the original array, just in the copied one. What am I missing?

Comment: This code example doesn't look complete.  I don't see how you would get an array that looks like your output based on what you posted.  I don't see `number` index anywhere.  I don't see where `$id` value is defined.  I don't see where you are adding a `MongoId` object into the array at all. I would think `print_r($array)` would result in something like `Array([0] => Array([number] => ?),[1] => Array([number] => ?), ...)`

Comment: @MikeBrant just a mistake in my question. It should have been "number" in the output & $i instead of $id

Comment: OK. That clears things up a bit.  Now the part that is bothering me is that I don;t understand why you would do the batch insert inside the loop with an ever-growing array.  This is going to cause the first records to be inserted multiple times (perhaps this is wanted, but your actual use case seems unclear).

Comment: I wanted to see how many records could I insert before MongoDB throwing an Exception. It doesn't mean anything in context of this question, it was just a consequence I've hit this weird behavior and I wanted to know what I miss in my knowledge.